# message element meta is not allowed here in PHPStorm

Tags: html, xml, phpstorm

Can someone explain me why I'm not allowed to use the `<meta>`-tag?

I always use it to ensure utf-8 encoding.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

My IDE (PHPStorm) throws the following message:

> Element meta is not allowed here

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0" "="), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 4):

Put the `meta` tag **inside** the `head`, the only children of the HTML element [should be `head` and `body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: In addition to only pasting a fixed code example you should also explain why this change is necessary.